# Apache subdomain proxy on virtualhost

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, proxy, subdomain, virtualhost

First of all, I'm using apache as the HTTP server for an app that's running on another port in the machine.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

The app recognizes the following URL: domain.com/accounts/profile, but what I want to do is use accounts.domain.com/profile

If I use another VirtualHost with a ProxyPass to add the subdomain, the app will not work, because the app only understands the route /accounts/profile if I do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName accounts.domain.com
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/accounts/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/accounts/
</VirtualHost>
```

and go to accounts.domain.com/profile, the app will only take the /profile/.
Can I achieve this by further configuring the VirtualHost and proxies?

I've also read on other places that maybe using rewrite I could fix it, much like how .httaccess files work.
I was trying that with something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^accounts\.domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule "^/(.*)$"  "http://domain.com/accounts/$1"  [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

and that ended up giving me a 502 Proxy Error

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /profile.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Additionally, a 502 Bad Gateway error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any tips on how to get this working? It's my first time using Apache for something other than hosting php webs and my .httaccess before were very very basic.

EDIT: Thanks to [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6715629/simon) in the comments for pointing out my mistake, I can't proxy the ServerName. I feel really dumb now.

Comment: Shouldn't your last rewrite redirect to `127.0.0.1:9000` instead of `domain.com` ?

Comment: You mean 
RewriteRule "^/(.*)$"  "http://127.0.0.1:9000/accounts/$1"  [P]?
Thanks a lot, I now see my mistake.
**This time it did work, seems like I hand't restarted the apache server before, if you answer the question I'll mark it as answered.